# OpenSSH intermittent error ( ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host ) on a public IP

Tags: openssh

I faced a very strange issue on one of my public SSH server. It was failing intermittently with the  error below:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

We all know that it's a generic one. Let me show you both client and server side logs.,

On SSH Client -

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config  
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *  
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0  
debug1: Connecting to 139.162.11.185 [139.162.11.185] port 22.  
debug1: Connection established.  
debug1: identity file /home/vivek/.ssh/id_rsa type -1  
debug1: identity file /home/vivek/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1  
debug1: identity file /home/vivek/.ssh/id_dsa type -1  
debug1: identity file /home/vivek/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1  
debug1: identity file /home/vivek/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1  
debug1: identity file /home/vivek/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1  
debug1: identity file /home/vivek/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1  
debug1: identity file /home/vivek/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1  
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0  
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.4  
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

On SSH Server

```
Feb  6 14:49:10 linsing2 sshd[19916]: Connection closed by 124.40.245.75  
Feb  6 14:49:16 linsing2 sshd[19935]: Connection closed by 124.40.245.75  
Feb  6 14:49:20 linsing2 sshd[19937]: Connection closed by 124.40.245.75
```

The whole issue is intermittent.

- Is this due to any DDOS attack on SSH server which has already made so many connections?
- Or is this is due to Max_Connection limit on SSH server ? (But Max_Connects works on per network basis we tried from 3 different networks and got the same error)
- Or is there a possible chance of number of currently opened files or connections on the SSH server? (Note  - We don't have much users doing sftp or ssh)

Please share your thoughts, it would be helpful !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this due to any DDOS attack on SSH server which has already made so many connections?

Might be. You would find by running `ps aux | grep sshd` to find out how many connections are pending. This is affected by option `MaxStartups`

> Or is this is due to Max_Connection limit on SSH server ? (But Max_Connects works on per network basis we tried from 3 different networks and got the same error)

There is no "Max_Connection" limit in ssh server. There is option `MaxSessions`, but it applies only to amount of sessions per connection, ie. Multiplexing.

The logs looks like the connection got broken somewhere in the middle. Firewalls, other IDS?

Answer (score 4):

It was actually a DOS attack and it got solved after changing the ssh port & MaxStartups variable in /etc/ssh/sshd_config to ,

`port 2244
 MaxStartups 100`

Restart the service ,

```
service sshd restart
```